# override style IE10 CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10

I have statements like

```
.theClassOfThediv{
    left: 2076px;
}
```

But I override the same (for some special reason) in the css like

```
 #myParrentDiv .theClassOfThediv{
    left: 1076px;
    background-color:Red;
 }
```

All browsers take the override version. But IE 10 does not show it.

But if I take IE development tool bar and just tick the style #myParrentDiv .theClassOfThediv,the div automatically gets the overridden style.

How can I resolve this issue

:(

Comment: what does the ie10 development bar says on document mode?

Answer (score 2):

Just try with an !important text just after the value,

```
left: 1076px !important;
```

Comment: I've been having the same issues as well, and !important doesn't seem to do it for me. Maybe it will for the OP.